# Using Code First and pluralizing ONLY `DbSet<Entity> Entities` entries

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5, pluralize

I want to disable pluralization for database tables which is easy enough. However, I use reflection and T4 templates to generate my context class.

```
public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
public DbSet<Department> Department { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to use EF's to return pluralized names from within T4 templates so I can generate the following:

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
```

Some function like `string name = EF.GetPluralizedName("User");`, etc.

I am using VS2010 targeting .NET 4 in case that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use pluralization service it would be something like

```
string name = System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.
CreateService(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).Pluralize("User");
```